# wp_get_attachment_image function size argument not working if I also add a custom class

Tags: functions, images, post-thumbnails

I'm trying to output some images the right way, using the `wp_get_attachment_image` function. Here's how I do it:

```php
echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id, 'image-size', '', [ 'class' => 'some-class' );
```

The thing is, it retrieves the image-size only (and outputs it as a class), if I use the first two arguments, `$image_id` and `'image-size'`, like so:

```html
<img width="260" height="350" src="[image-src-link]" class="attachment-image-size size-img-size" alt="" loading="lazy" />
```

However, if I add a custom class as the fourth argument, as demonstrated in the first paragraph, it somehow overrides the image size and uses only the custom class, so this is what I get:

```html
<img width="260" height="350" src="[image-src-link]" class="some-class" alt="" loading="lazy" />
```

I absolutely don't get what I'm doing wrong. I found [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/132171/wp-get-attachment-image-not-working-when-trying-to-add-width-and-height-attrib), the note in the accepted answer implies that this is some kind of bug, but the thread is almost 8 years old, and I think the bug would've been resolved by now. Also, the [WordPress Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/) clearly states that the `wp_get_attachment_image` can take four arguments and says absolutely nothing about image size and custom class conflicts, so I'm officially out of ideas.
Could somebody please steer me in the right direction?

Comment: that parameter does not add classes, it sets the classes, you can't use it to add classses, only replace/set them. What's the problem that required you to do this though? Can you provide the context? It looks like you devised a solution and asked how to fix it rather than asking about the original problem, if you share that then there may be alternatives you hadn't considered

Comment: Ah, okay, didn't know that it actually replaces the image size with a custom class. The context? I basically wanted to add an image size AND bottom margin to an image and thought it'd be more efficient to apply the custom class containing the bottom margin directly to the <img> element, instead of wrapping the <img> inside a <div> and then adding a class to that <div>, but seems there's not other way then?

Comment: usually there's some CSS pseudo-selector that can fix these issues but without knowing why you want to add a margin I can't advise. e.g. is this the last item in a list? Or a specific image in a particular layout? You've hidden most of the context and information in the process of trying to make this general/generic so it's very difficult to suggest something. Likewise there are other options from the PHP end but they depend on information/context you haven't shared

Answer (score 1):

Just as Tom mentioned in the comments above. The fourth parameter of `wp_get_attachment_image` sets the value, not adds to it so it will override the auto generated class.

If you need the size class and your custom class you can simply add both of them manually like so...

```php
echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id, 'image-size', '', [
  'class' => 'some-class attachment-image-size size-img-size'
] );
```

I